# is there a logic error in for loop's mentioned conditions?

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

The code when injected into an active window containing youtube should redirect it to g.co
however it is not doing so. I think it is because `for` loop has some error but I am not sure.

```
var current_title = document.title.toLowerCase();
var blacklisted = ["youtube","vimeo"].map(v => v.toLowerCase());
var isurlnotok = false;
var websiteisnotok = false;
var item_url;
for (var i =0; i <= blacklisted.length || isurlnotok || websiteisnotok; i++) {
    item_url = blacklisted[i];
    isurlnotok = current_url.includes(item_url);
    websiteisnotok = current_title.includes(item_url);
}
if (isurlnotok || websiteisnotok){
  window.location = "https://g.co";
}
console.log("url: "+current_url+"\ntitle: "+current_title+"\nisurlnotok:"+isurlnotok+"\niswebsitenotok:"+websiteisnotok);
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't make sense: `blacklisted.length || isurlnotok|| websiteisnotok`

why would you have an or (||) and then try to access blacklisted[i] on the very next line?

what you probably mean is:

```
for (var i =0;i<=blacklisted.length;i++){
    item_url=blacklisted[i];
    if(!isurlnotok)
        isurlnotok=current_url.includes(item_url);
    if(!websiteisnotok)
        websiteisnotok=current_title.includes(item_url);
}
if (isurlnotok|| websiteisnotok){window.location = "https://g.co";}
```